# Angular reset TransferState data on route change

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-transfer-state

I'm using Angular with server-side rendering and TransferState to transfer http data from server to browser. Here is my code:

```js
getProducts() {
    let products = this.tstate.get(PRODUCT_KEY, null as any);
    if (products) {
        return of(products);
    }

    return this.http.post<any>(config.baseUrl+ 'product', {}).pipe(map(
        data => {
            this.tstate.set(PRODUCT_KEY, data as any);
            return data;
        }
    ))
}
```

In the first load, I get the data from http request. Then the state is initializing. After that, when the route changes, still transfer state keeps the data, so I can't send the request to get the data. Any idea how to reset transfer state in route changing?

Comment: Why don't you unset the data right after retriving it from the cache?

Comment: @David This even doesn't solve the problem. At first time, imagine I unset the from the cache and it send a new request, then I go to another menu, and come back to the previous menu, still, it will use the cache.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. If you want to use the transfer state only once, then unset the key after retrieving the data and do not cache the next requests. The other option is to listen to router events and clear the cache when you want

Comment: What do you mean by `do not cache the next requests`? (Sorry I explained in a bad way, let me explain again)

Comment: I mean do not use `this.tstate.set(PRODUCT_KEY, data as any);` if you are client side

Comment: Imagine I have menu1, menu2, and menu3. I have http request in menu2. First I open menu1. Then I go to menu2. It sends http request and saves the cache. I go to menu3, then go to menu 2, and it uses the cache (after that I can unset the cache).

Comment: Ok, let me test your workaround.

Comment: @David Thank you, it seems it works fine. If you add your comment as an answer, I would accept it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to router events and unset cached data after navigation

```
constructor(private router: Router,
//...)
{
  this.router.events.subscribe(evt => {
  if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
  {
    this.tstate.remove(PRODUCT_KEY);
  }

}
```

Or you could stop setting transfer data if you are client side

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
//...)
{
}

getProducts() {
    let products = this.tstate.get(PRODUCT_KEY, null as any);
    if (products) {
        this.tstate.remove(PRODUCT_KEY);
        return of(products);
    }

    return this.http.post<any>(config.baseUrl+ 'product', {}).pipe(map(
        data => {
            if(!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)
            {
                this.tstate.set(PRODUCT_KEY, data as any);
            }

            return data;
        }
    ))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer the second way.